# How to create subset of dataframe using conditional statement on column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Very new to panda and trying to practice so I can handle bigger data size.
I'm trying to create a conditional statement using 3 criteria: Gene, Locus, and .
If Gene and Locus are matching (identical), compare FPKM between those two and delete the data with smaller FPKM.
Else move onto the next Gene and repeat the process. So it keeps filtering out duplicates.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GWTs.png)

So far this is what I've tried:

```
#if Gene and Locus are the same
if s_filt.loc[s_filt['Gene'] == s_filt['Gene']] and s_filt.loc[s_filt['Locus'] ==s_filt.loc['Locus']]=True:
if s_filt['q0_FPKM'] > s_filt['q0_FPKM']: #compare q0_FPKM
s_filter.drop() #delete entire row with smaller q0_FPKM
else:
pass
```

Feeling a bit picked how to frame the second criteria (compare FPKM) and deleting the data which doesn't meet the criteria.

Apologies in advance if I'm making rookie mistakes here, still learning...

Comment: You'll get much more help if your question is easy to reproduce. I don't believe that anyone here will create the DataFrame from an image, hand us something we can copy and paste. Then add what the output that your code produces looks like and what the output has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it iteratively, you can use [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to only keep the biggest FPKM in case of duplicated Gene and Locus:

```
s_filt = pd.DataFrame({'Gene': ['BAGE4', 'BAGE2', 'AGSK1', 'DAZ4', 'LOC1001333', 'DA74', 'DAZ4', 'LOC1001333', 'AGSK1', 'LOC1001333'], 
                   'Locus': ['chr21:11020841-11098925', 'chr21:11020841-11098925', 'chr15:82764077-82798323', 
                             'chrY:26979966-27053187', 'chr5:180750506-180755196', 'chrY:25365580-25437503', 
                             'chrY:26909215-26959639', 'chr5:180750506-180755196', 'chr15:83140663-83182901',
                             'chr1:323891-328581'], 
                   'q0_FPKM': [0, 0, 0.0131109, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0.013122, 0]})

# drop_duplicates keeps the first duplicate (the one with largest FPKM) by default.
s_filt = s_filt.sort_values('q0_FPKM', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Gene', 'Locus']).sort_index()

print(s_filt)
```

```
         Gene                     Locus   q0_FPKM
0       BAGE4   chr21:11020841-11098925  0.000000
1       BAGE2   chr21:11020841-11098925  0.000000
2       AGSK1   chr15:82764077-82798323  0.013111
3        DAZ4    chrY:26979966-27053187  0.000000
4  LOC1001333  chr5:180750506-180755196  2.000000
5        DA74    chrY:25365580-25437503  0.000000
6        DAZ4    chrY:26909215-26959639  1.000000
8       AGSK1   chr15:83140663-83182901  0.013122
9  LOC1001333        chr1:323891-328581  0.000000
```

Doing it this way will be much faster and more applicable to larger datasets.

### EDIT - only looking at the gene:

```
s_filt_2 = s_filt.sort_values('q0_FPKM', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='Gene').sort_index()

print(s_filt_2)
```

```
         Gene                     Locus   q0_FPKM
0       BAGE4   chr21:11020841-11098925  0.000000
1       BAGE2   chr21:11020841-11098925  0.000000
4  LOC1001333  chr5:180750506-180755196  2.000000
5        DA74    chrY:25365580-25437503  0.000000
6        DAZ4    chrY:26909215-26959639  1.000000
8       AGSK1   chr15:83140663-83182901  0.013122
```

Comment: Follow if i want to further filter out from here to filter out comparing identical genes, not looking at loci, but keep the gene that has bigger FPKM is this the right code to do it?
`s_filt_2 = s_filt.sort_values('Gene').drop_duplicates(subset=['q0_FPKM']).sort_index()`

or is it  `s_filt_2 = s_filt.sort_values('q0_FPKM', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Gene']).sort_index()`

Comment: @EmilyNwo the second one. First sort, then drop duplicates. See the edit to my answer, I added the code and result of that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the second one to see if that was the correct one and turned out it was :)